# How to manipulate a Fourier sine series?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, fourier-analysis

I would like to plot the Fourier sine series for $f(x) = x$.

I would like to manipulate the parameter `n` from $0$ to $10$ and plot the sine waves over $(0,1)$. My code below does not work; what is wrong?

```
Manipulate[Plot[FourierSinSeries[x, x, n], {x, 0, 1}], {n, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Tried adding `Evaluated -> True` to `Plot[]`?

Comment: Also, for this function, n cannot be zero, so you'll need to change {n,0,10} to {n,1,10}. If you only intended to plot for integer n, then it's {n,1,10,1}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the comment:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[FourierSinSeries[x, x, n]], {x, 0, 10}], {n, 1, 10}]
```

What is happening here is that `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll` so that the `FourierSinSeries` function has not been evaluated (at the points `n`) when the plot occurs. There are some examples of this in the documentation for `Plot`: for instance look at the `Neat Example` and try removing the `Evaluated` command -- the plot will disappear.